# What does it mean for a manifold to "look like" another manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In Carroll's introduction to general relativity textbook, the following question is an exercise at the end of Chapter 2:

"By clever choice of coordinate charts, can we make $\mathbf R^2$ look like a one-dimensional manifold? Can we make $\mathbf R^1$ look like a two-dimensional manifold? If so, explicitly construct an appropriate atlas, and if not, explain why not. The point of this problem is to provoke you to think deeply about what a manifold is; it can't be answered rigorously without going into more details about topological spaces. In particular, you might have to forget that you already know a definition of an "open set" in the original $\mathbf R^2$ or $\mathbf R^1$, and define them as being appropriately inherited from the $\mathbf R^1$ or $\mathbf R^2$ to which they are being mapped."

What does he mean by making $\mathbf R^2$/$\mathbf R^1$ "look like" the appropriate manifolds? The only criteria of comparison he gives in the chapter if that of a diffeomorphism: if there is a diffeomorphism between two manifolds, they are "the same". Since he mentioned having to go into detail about topological spaces, I went online and found another comparison criterion (comparing two topologies of a set, and how the partial ordering of the set of all topologies on a given set can be used to compare them), but I don't know if that applies here or not.

Note that I'm looking for possible answers to the question in the title, not the exercise given in the textbook; I'm still trying to solve the problem, and need a push in the right direction rather than a complete solution. Also, I'm new to differential geometry and I just got the textbook to learn GR.

Comment: I think it is clear from the exposition that this is not meant to be a rigorous exercise.  Rather, the goal seems to be to get the reader to come up with their own definition of "looks like", in order to (hopefully) better understand why the definitions in future chapters matter.

Comment: I see. So it's more of a conceptual problem than an actual one? What about the remark of "inheriting" the concept of openness from the manifold being mapped to? That seems like a very specific detail to add...

Comment: I honestly don't quite know what the author is aiming for, but I think that the idea is that you can ignore the topology of the original manifold, and instead think of maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into that "manifold".  If we declare these maps to be continuous (or bicontinuous, even), then the "manifold" inherits a topology from $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Again, I don't know what the author is *actually* trying to say, but this seems to be the general gist of it.

Comment: Generally, to say that a space $X$ looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$ means that each point in $X$ has a neighborhood homeomorphic, diffeomorphic, or etc. to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The author also might be going for something like invariance of domain.

Comment: @anomaly That is my intuition, but the author is specifically asking the reader to *ignore* these kinds of things. It is a very weird thought exercise, if you ask me. :/

Comment: @XanderHenderson: No argument there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know how much Carroll has introduced at this stage, but a smooth manifold consists at the very minimum of the following information: an integer $n\geq 0$, a set $M$ together with a choice $\mathcal{A}$ called an *atlas*. An atlas is an object whose elements are pairs, $(U,\phi)$, called *charts*. These charts are then required to satisfy a few conditions:

- each $\phi[U]$ is supposed to be open in $\Bbb{R}^n$,
- for each pair $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ in $\mathcal{A}$, $\phi[U\cap V],\psi[U\cap V]$ must be open in $\Bbb{R}^n$
- the maps $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi[U\cap V]\to \phi[U\cap V]$, and $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}:\phi[U\cap V]\to\psi[U\cap V]$ are supposed to be $C^{\infty}$.
- the atlas must cover $M$, meaning the union of all $U$ as $(U,\phi)$ varies in $\mathcal{A}$ must equal $M$. Or more explicitly, for each $p\in M$, there must exist some $(U,\phi)\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $p\in U$.

Ok I’m glossing over the fact that after one has the definition of $\mathcal{A}$, a *smooth structure on $M$* is actually an equivalence class of atlases (the equivalence relation being that the union must be an atlas still) or what amounts to the same thing, one considers a *maximal atlas*.

Anyway, the point of this question is for you to think about if it is possible to take the set $M=\Bbb{R}^n$ (forget everything else you know about it temporarily; i.e forget grid lines, forget Euclidean distances, forget all of that. Just think of this as a big box of tuples) and construct an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ such that with this atlas, $(M,[\mathcal{A}])$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$ (with $m$ possibly different from $n$), and furthermore whether it is possible to make it so that $(M,[\mathcal{A}])$ is diffeomorphic to the usual smooth manifold $(\Bbb{R}^m,[\mathcal{A}_{\text{standard}}])$.

I’ll spoil the answer for you, but let you figure out the details (I disagree that you cannot answer this rigorously at this stage (even if you don’t know what a topological space in general is, as long as you know what an atlas is and what the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}^n$, in terms of open balls is)). The answer is yes, such an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ does exist. In fact, I can even take the Cantor set (or even worse, a fat Cantor set $F\subset\Bbb{R}$) and I can equip it with an atlas such that the result is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{2023}$ with its usual smooth structure.

So, the purpose of this question, as already mentioned in the text, is “to provoke you to think deeply about what a manifold is”, and in particular, to get you to keep your instincts at bay and proceed only with the definitions in an almost robotic manner “smooth manifold = set + maximal smooth atlas” and to make you understand the role of each part of the definition. In this process you’ll learn the key lesson that a manifold is not just a set of points!

Comment: In the book, he does describe the concepts of charts and atlases, and produces almost word-for-word what your definition of a chart is. So I guess you're saying that "looks like" must mean diffeomorphic? Also what is $\mathcal{A}_{standard}$ specifically?

Comment: @Chidi on $\Bbb{R}^m$, you consider $\mathcal{A}_{\text{standard},\Bbb{R}^m}=\{(\Bbb{R}^m,\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^m})\}$, i.e it is the atlas consisting of only one chart which is simply the identity map. Yes, in this context, “looks like” means “diffeomorphic” (but of course this word is meaningless until one specifies carefully what the manifolds on the domain and target are, including all the smooth structures etc).